# Use custom domain for Firebase Functions which is not in 'us-central1' region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud

Is there a way to register a custom domain for my Firebase Functions which are hosted on a not `'us-central1'` region
For example my Firebase Functions looks like this: `https://asia-southeast2-my-first-firebase-function/`

I read an article on Firebase Document related to my issue https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

But Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in `us-central1` only.

Answer (score 0):

Export your functions like this

```
exports.YOURFUNCTIONAME = functions
  .region("southamerica-east1")
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
```

so your next deploys will update the region